# keep track with the distance between user's location and other coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to send notification when user is 300 meter from any map pin (all pins coming from an API)

I calculate the distance by ..

```
currentLocation = CLLocationManager()
currentLocation!.distance(from: pinLoc)
```

I get the distance right, however, to keep tracking the user's location (Driving) I have to put the my code in the (didUpdateLocations) function, which will keep looping forever [I don't use stopUpdatingLocation() because I need to keep getting the user's location]

Is there any other ways to keep getting the user's location (coordinates) constantly without having to go inside infinite loop!

I also use

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
```

To track the user's location on the map.

Thank you.

Comment: You can monitor the region. It has some limitations but depends on your implementation can work great https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: Do you mean I set each map pin as a region, then track the user if joined that region? Will that be a right structure?

Comment: Yes and no, you monitor each region. Then you have the delegate method that fires when the condition match. Don’t need to track the user. You have some sketches on the doc

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to work on it in the way you described. Seems it's the way to go. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use userLocation property of mapView to keep getting the user's location (coordinates) constantly.

```
mapView.userLocation.coordinate
```